# Remove a file starting with special character

Tags: centos7, vesta

How to delete such "?file.php"

When I try to delete this file or the directory containing this file,  arises an error "cannot remove input / output error" appears

["?file.php"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sVI8.png)

Comment: Can you please who how you are trying to delete it? Likely the `?` needs to be escaped.

Comment: rm -rf "folder that contain this file"

Comment: rm \?file.php - also doesn't work

Comment: Maybe this thread will help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82856/delete-all-files-starting-with-a-question-mark You should edit the question to include your code.